# Javascript: changing input file type?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple HTML file input:

```
<input type="file" id="file" onchange="__func">
```

Once I load the file in the input, I call `__func`:

```
function __func(event)
{
    let file = event.target.files[0];
        file.type = 'text/csv';
}
```

Problem is when I attempt to change the file type within `__func`, either type of file does not change, either I receive the error:

> TypeError: "setting getter-only property "type""

How can I dynamically change file type using javascript? I need to do it because I'm sending the file via a FormData wrapper, and because it's plain CSV the content type is not properly detected and set to `application/octet-stream` automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use slice method to create a new File Blob.

```
const blob = file.slice(0, file.size, "text/csv")
```